# What can be said of the element x if $x \in \cup \{ A-B|A \in F\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

Having a hard time analyzing the statement. What can be said of the element x if $x \in \cup \{ A-B|A \in F\}$? Disregarding intersection first, I have encountered somewhat similar forms but they were not applied to sets. Example: $y \in \{n^2|n \in N \} $ is transformed as $\exists y \in N(y=n^2)$ (from book). How to deal this types but with sets?

For now, this is my attempt:
$$x \in \{ y| \exists M(M \in \{ A-B|A \in F\} \land y \in M )\}$$
$$\exists M(M \in \{ A-B|A \in F\} \land x \in M )$$
$$\exists M(\exists M(M \in F \land ( M-B)) \land x \in M )$$

I am not sure about the transition to the 2nd to the 3rd line. 
Subquestions related to the problem.

1. Are $y \in\{x \in S|P(x)\}$ and $y \in\{P(x)|x \in S\}$ different? I think the former is $\forall y \in SP(y)$ and the latter is $\exists y \in SP(y)$?
2. $\exists M$ appeared twice is there away to make the analysis simpler?

Soft question. What tags should I use for these kinds of question?

Answer (score 1):

Well in a slightly simpler case you have
$$ x\in \bigcup_{A\in F}A \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \exists A\in F(\exists y\in A(x=y))$$

And so we follow this pattern to get
\begin{align*}&x\in\bigcup_{A\in F}(A-B)\\\Leftrightarrow& \exists A\in F(\exists y\in (A-B)(x=y))\\\Leftrightarrow& \exists A\in F(\exists y\in A(\forall b\in B(y\ne b\land y=x)))\end{align*}

Comment: What does equal mean in the case of sets? Is it the bi-conditional connectives: <=>? Also, did I question 1 right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're third line means. You're using a set $M-B$ as a proposition? With regards to your questions, I'm not sure what you want the interpretation of $y\in\{P(x)|x\in S\}$ to be. You should look up set-builder notation to understand what it means. I'm not really sure how you've gotten to propositional calculus without it. You should be careful with your analysis and try to think about what sort of thing (e.g set, element of set, proposition, etc) each symbol or phrase is in a proposition in future

Comment: In the 1st to 2nd line I applied union of  family of set. 2nd to third line i got rid of the brackets. In the  book I am using $\exists M \in F (P (x))$ is equivalent to $\exists M (M \in F \land P(x))$. I more comfortable in using the latter most of the time.

Comment: Look at the line. $M-B$ is a set, not a proposition, no?

Comment: I am not too sure of what I did from second to third though (removing the bracket) hence it is one of the subquestion.

Comment: What can you suggest to evaluate this one $M \in \{ A-B|A \in F\}$

Comment: I am trying to point out that the third line has, as far as I can tell, no coherent mathematical meaning and that therefore either (a) I am missing some weird way of interpreting the difference of two sets as a proposition or (b) you've gotten confused and need to go back and try to work out what's going on with your derivation (focusing on the bit I pointed out)

Comment: $M\in \{A-B | A\in F\} $ is equivalent to $\exists M(\exists A(A\in F\land M=B-A))$, if you like but it all feels a bit weird to me

Comment: Now that I think about it seems does not make sense. Might M∈{A−B|A∈F} be equivalent to $\exists A \in F(M=A-B)$ <=>$\exists A  (A \in F \land (M=A-B))$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65675/discussion-between-tighten-and-dan-robertson).